# It seems that my App can't retrieve info from SQL database.. why? (Xcode, Objective-C)

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, database, xcode

Function to load/read database

```
- (void) cargarBaseDeDatos
{
    BOOL exito;
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"territoriumDB.sql"];

    exito = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    if (exito) return;
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"territoriumDB.sql"];

    exito = [filemanager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath: writableDBPath error: &error];
    if(!exito)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }      
}
```

List Events class, supposed to retrieve the events title from the database and display it on a table view controller, but when I run the app the rows are blank. I already linked the table view controller to the class.

```
    #import "ListarEventoViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ListarEventoViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *eventos;
}

@end

@implementation ListarEventoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    eventos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self cargarEventos];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [eventos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSDictionary *dic = [eventos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"titulo"];
    return cell;
}


- (void) cargarEventos
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *sentencia;
    if (sqlite3_open([appDelegate.dataBasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *sentenciaSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from eventos"];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[sentenciaSQL UTF8String], -1, &sentencia, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(sentencia)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                NSString *titulo = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sentencia, 0)];
                [dic setValue:titulo forKey:@"titulo"];
                [eventos addObject:dic];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sentencia);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}

@end
```

Comment: Which iOS version you using?? Its seems like there are couple of updates in iOS 10 with regards to SQLITE

Comment: iOS 10. I already added the sqlite3 library to the project

Comment: Debug and check if there is any error? if any post error log.